# Fetch api cors request throws error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', but Pre-Flight response shows header is set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch

I'm using the fetch api to send json data to a third party api and view the response. The endpoint I'm hitting is supposed to have CORS enabled for any origin, but I'm getting an error that says `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`.

If I send a request with the `OPTIONS` method to force it to be Pre-Flighted, I can see that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is in fact set, as you can see below...

[image]

And here's my fetch request...

```js
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

EDIT: I should probably mention that I do not have control over the server. Also, I'm hitting the api from localhost, not sure if that has any implications...

Answer (score 0):

Instead "*" in headers. pass your domain "www.example.com". And even if that's not work then add " Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM www.example.com""

Comment: It's a third party api so I can't make changes server-side.

Comment: Then check the MIME type of response. If MIME type of response is application/json or other just add those in  like  "'Accept':'application/json' " in your request headers

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out the answer to my original question, but there's a simple workaround: a proxy server.

The [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) package makes it super easy. Just use the example code in the README and point your fetch request at `http://localhost:[proxy port]/[original url]`.